# How to build a searchable list with scroll in adaptive card as WhoBot in MS Teams bot framework

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am developing a MS Teams bot using Bot Framework with nodejs.

After the user asks a question, my bot has a list of items to display as WhoBot does, as shown in the below image. Does anybody know how to build this beautiful and clean menu results with a scroll? Or who can guide me on the tutorial or webpage on how to make this? Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the list card implementation. You can find the docs related to it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/design-effective-cards#lists. Regarding the search logic, you will need to implement it at the backend in your application and pass the items to list card.